# git says "fatal: confused by unstable object source data"

Tags: git

Just for fun, I am trying to put around 85GB of mostly-around-6MB binary files into git. Git chugs along for a while but invariably fails about halfway through with the message "fatal: confused by unstable object source data" followed by a SHA1. Do you know why? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Either

- one or more files are being modified during your operation, or
- something is causing inconsistent reads (e.g. failing hardware).

Short version: Git’s developers did not intend for it to be used on volatile files.

Due to the layout<sup>*</sup> that  Git uses for “loose objects” and the limited filesystem semantics that it assumes<sup>**</sup>, Git must know the first byte (two hex characters) of the object name (SHA-1) of a new object before it can start storing that object.

<sup>*
The `objects/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/` directories. See [`gitrepository-layout`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html).</sup>

<sup>**
Specifically, it needs to be able to do “atomic” file renames. Certain filesystems (usually network filesystems; specifically [AFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System), I believe) only guarantee rename atomicity when the source and the destination of a rename are inside the same directory.</sup>

Currently, Git does two SHA-1 passes over each *new* file. The first pass is used to check whether whether Git already knows about the contents of the file (whether its SHA-1 object name already exists in the object store). If the object already exists, the second pass is not made.

For new contents (object was not already in the object store), the file is read a second time while compressing and computing the SHA-1 of the data being compressed. The compressed data is written to a temporary file that is only renamed to its final loose object name if the initial SHA-1 (“already stored?” check) matches the later SHA-1 (hash of the data that was compressed and written). If these SHA-1 hashes do not match, then Git shows the error message you are seeing and aborts. This error checking was added in [748af44c63](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=748af44c63ea6fec12690f1693f3dddd963e88d5) which was first released in Git 1.7.0.2.

Comment: Pretty sure that it's not volatile, but it's still been *very* instructive to read more about the internals of git. I guess now I've got to go and make sure that my disk isn't failing.

Comment: sure would be nice if git said "fatal: confused by unstable object source data" followed by a SHA1 AND THEN FOLLOWED BY THE FILE.  Pretty annoying that it doesn't tell you what file is volatile... If it did I might reasonably add it or the directory to my .gitignore

Comment: so what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 17):

There is another possibility, even if remote. That would be a really big file (e.g 3 or more gb) putting it simply, git is unable to handle it. We found that error trying to create a repository in a structure with huge files

Comment: Just had this happen with some multi-gigabyte log file that snuck into a git work tree.

Comment: Large (but stable) files definitely cause this error. The fact that the error message is misleading, and that Git doesn't tell you up front about the size is a shortcoming, at least for now, of Git.

I've tried git-annex, a promising-looking way of dealing with large files, but so far have not been able to get it to work on OS/X.

Answer (score 4):

From the [source](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=sha1_file.c;hb=1c2ab4303354da23ff74ce2ea4a99b69fcfae825), the blob's sha1 is computed twice:

- write_sha1_file_prepare
- write_loose_object

both called from write_sha1_file (there's also a path from force_object_loose, but it is used for repacks).

The first hash is used to check if the object is already known (though git tries its best to get the filesystem's reassurance that files are unmodified, a `touch` or such would make it lose track); the second is the hash of the data that is actually fed to zlib for compression, then written.

The second hash might be a bit more expensive to compute due to zlib, which may explain why two hashes are computed (though that seems to be historical accident, and I'm guessing the performance cost when adding a new object has more impact than the cpu win when detecting spurious changes). Someone could add a fallback so that the write_changed_sha1 existence checking logic is redone with the new sha1, so that those unstable files can also be added. That would be useful for backups, when a few of the files being added are open.

Answer (score 3):

Two theories:

- Something is writing to these files while you are trying to put them into git.
- You have some sort of disk/memory failure causing data corruption.

Answer (score 2):

Although other responses have provided a very good explanation on why the error occurs here is a possible solution to the problem:

Track down the problematic file, adding -v to your git add command will give you some clue about the problematic file:

```
git add -Av
```

The problem might just be that the file is too large (a zipped source, some sql data file): add it to .gitignore

In fact a good practice is to regularly configure your .gitignore file to avoid compiled and compressed files like in: https://gist.github.com/octocat/9257657

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you try to git svn clone or git svn fetch a repository on a btrfs filesystem, maybe something to do with race condition or atomicity inside btrfs cow feature.

Example :

```
git svn --authors-file=authors.map clone http://svn.example.com/svn/repo repo
```

or

```
cd repo; git svn --authors-file=../authors.map fetch
```

I found a workaround by setting you base working directory without copy-on-write :

```
chattr +C .
```

Then you need to duplicate all your data (ex) :

```
cp -fr repo repo.new; rm -fr repo; mv -f repo.new repo

cp authors.map authors.map.new; mv -f authors.map.new authors.map
```

Then it should not fail (and run faster).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, just large amount of added files can cause this message.  Committing the same files in several steps wasn't a problem.