# git - Limit on what can be stored?

Tags: git

I have been having intermittent issues with git.  I am using it to version all of my files that are not volatile.

The error:
fatal: confused by unstable object source data for

Now, I originally had this problem on another drive and when I did, I saw an error in dmesg indicating that EXT-4 was unable to read some meta-data.  That led me to believe the drive was failing.  So, I unmounted the drive and ran the fsck tools and everything checked out okay.  Do I need to do anything more in depth since git is complaining?

Secondly, I just got this error on a newer drive and did NOT get any errors in dmesg indicating any problems reading meta-data in the file system.  I am certain that no other processes are writing to it as I used lsof.

Any ideas on how to proceed?  I am storing large, binary files in one case (several GB) and a mix of files in the other.

Similar post:
[git says "fatal: confused by unstable object source data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423827/git-says-fatal-confused-by-unstable-object-source-data)

Walter

Comment: `git fsck --full` is always worth a try to test the consistency of the git storage. Also, checking the RAM of the machine is often worth a try :)

Comment: GIT isnt' an acronym :) It is Git

Comment: @Mohamed: I used to edit everyone's questions to fix that, and Git vs. git (it's git, not Git), but it's a losing battle...

Comment: I have 6GB of ram and NO swap, I am guessing that I probably need swap for this to work as my file is larger than 6GB ...

Comment: @Jefromi: I don't care about the spelling, but it seems to me that http://www.git-scm.com says `Git` - except in the logo of the page.

Comment: @Frerich: Looks like I got burned by something I read in a git manpage or commit message somewhere. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you are trying to add always-changing volatile file or something low-level is failing.

[git says "fatal: confused by unstable object source data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423827/git-says-fatal-confused-by-unstable-object-source-data/4423887#4423887)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something to do with Copy-On-Write feature in ext4 ?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42299634/7491491