# Index mismatch error when performing 'git svn fetch'

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I've been working with a remote SVN repository using git svn for a while without any problems.  The other day, I typed `git svn fetch` and got the following index mismatch error.  I tried the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073956/how-to-resolve-a-git-index-mismatch-problem), but it didn't work.

Here's the error:

```
$ git svn fetch
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (175002): RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on '/clients/!svn/bc/50511/foo/devsite': REPORT of '/clients/!svn/bc/50511/foo/devsite': 200 OK (https://svn.example.com)
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Index mismatch: 2b1371fbceb67b54e6afb805bcc65483e7eb381a != 99c95d43e7a473492b738ccc1f413911c43f195e
rereading c69879814b55f39121372a395fe15896e749b46a
        M       trunk/email-landing/landing-looking.html
        M       trunk/email-landing/landing-nurture.html
        A       trunk/email-landing/images/register-now-screenshot.png
        A       trunk/email-landing/images/dark-checkmark.png
        A       trunk/email-landing/images/logo.jpg
        A       trunk/email-landing/images/logo.png
        M       trunk/email-landing/landing-event.html
RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on '/clients/!svn/vcc/default': REPORT of '/clients/!svn/vcc/default': 200 OK (https://svn.example.com) at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 5653
```

**EDIT:** I have tried re-installing cygwin (and thus git-svn).  I have also tried cloning a new repository via `git svn clone` -- same error.

Answer (score 1):

Despite a re-install, your configs files may remain untouched. Check out your .gitconfig file and look for errors in your subversion path. Also make sure that the "fetch" parameter in your .gitconfig is pointed to the right branch.

Also, going by the errors.. line 5653 in the git-svn file is:

($full_url =~ m#^https?://# &&

So, the error has to be in the svn url.

Comment: The svn URL in the `.git/config` file of the repository is correct.  In fact, it appears to connect to the server.  I also tried to clone a whole new repository with the same error.  My `~/.gitconfig` file only has `name` and `email` set.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try and fetch/clone by using another user account on your system, just to eliminate any local profile settings corruption (if your repo allows!).