# git svn clone stops with the error : Index mismatch

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

While running the command git svn clone, I get the below error and migration stops :

```
Index mismatch: 168586039d6b675e5ba51706ea759f8ee701a538 != 45485a0f950096c26425196ab7e7fd54c042d4cc
rereading 284599fe3bd0720c7c516191d67031d855d6a3c6
Svndiff data contains backward-sliding source view: Svndiff has backwards-sliding source views at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.
```

I tried to find the solution almost everywhere. But no luck. 
Anyone else has faced this problem?

Comment: look at this question [How do I resolve a git-svn index mismatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073956/how-do-i-resolve-a-git-svn-index-mismatch). Solve this your question?

Comment: Thanks @SwissCodeMen. I have already checked this. None of the answers solved my problem.