# git svn rebase errors

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

When I do `git svn rebase` on `trunk-svn` (which is my local copy of the SVN repo's `trunk` branch), I get the following error:

```
fatal: invalid upstream 'refs/remotes/origin/trunk'
rebase refs/remotes/origin/trunk: command returned error: 128
```

On a different branch, I get a different error:

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

Checking out a new local copy of a different remote branch (which I had never checked out before) works fine, both the `git checkout -b ...` and the `git svn rebase` (with subsequent `git svn rebase` saying "up to date").

As far as I know, nothing changed about my local repository or the remote—this just started happening one day.

Here is what the SVN bit of `.git/config` looks like:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://foo.bar.com/svn
    fetch = REPONAME/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = REPONAME/branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    tags = REPONAME/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

This is the same as what I see when I do a fresh `git svn clone -s` of the repo. (I don't want to just use the fresh clone because I have a LOT of unmerged work in my old copy.)

And here are the relevant bits of `.git/config` for the branches in question:

```
[branch "trunk-svn"]
    remote = gitlab
    merge = refs/heads/trunk-svn
[branch "bugfix-svn"]
    remote = gitlab
    merge = refs/heads/bugfix-svn
[remote "gitlab"]
    url = git@gitlab.company.com:user.name/repo_name.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gitlab/*
```

Previous troubleshooting attempts have failed:

1. `git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn refs/remotes/gitlab/trunk-svn`: No apparent output of this command; same error happens with `git svn rebase` on `trunk-svn`.
2. `git fsck` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073956/how-do-i-resolve-a-git-svn-index-mismatch#comment4378841_4073956)) shows only dangling trees, commits, and blobs—i.e., nothing appears to be missing.
3. Removing `.git/svn/.caches` (idea derived from a suggestion [here](https://vitalidze.github.io/2013/06/27/Git-SVN-command-error-128/)) makes no difference.
4. Adding `rewriteRoot` and `rewriteUUID` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061493/2965321) makes no difference.

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Let me know if I can provide any more info that might be useful.

Comment: `refs/remotes/` in Git is a namespace in which we find "subdirectories" (in quotes because these things aren't exactly *directories*, they just behave the same way) where the "directory name" is the remote. So `refs/remotes/git-svn` would never be appropriate; `refs/remotes/git-svn/something` would be the remote-tracking name for a remote named `git-svn`. I don't actually use `git-svn` myself so I can't say if it uses namespaces the way Git does, but that seems very likely. The `svn-remote` section you quote looks like it holds refspecs, or prototype refspecs.

Comment: Meanwhile: `fatal: invalid upstream 'refs/remotes/origin/trunk'` just means that `refs/remotes/origin/trunk` does not point to a commit. How and why *that* came about is the first question to solve: is that the right name and should it exist and point to a commit, and if so, why doesn't it? Or, if it's the wrong name, how did something come to generate it here, what's the right name, etc?

Comment: As a workaround: if you have a good fresh clone which is working OK — you may add the old clone as a "remote" (`git remote add oldclone file://.../oldrepo`), and simply pull the unmerged commits into the fresh clone, then drop the old one. I haven't used git-svn in years either; but as a general impression, diving into its source was the most reliable approach to figuring out what went astray. Even the manpage has omissions, there're `svn-remote.*` namespace remapping options which are handled in the perl code, but not documented in the manpage. HTH