# Migration issues from SVN to Git

Tags: svn, git-svn

Hi I am not able to my repository from SVN to Git using 'git svn' tool..

I am facing below error

```
$ git svn fetch
Index mismatch: a93a7f4289f88b70ba85c8f6210e3c64b97447d5 != 20979407f93a6908d2dadee058774021b68f80af
rereading 44999ef977dddeed551f4822d25763b1c38a7307
        M       parser/service/src/main/java/service/Add.java
        M       parser/service/src/main/java/service/DependencyUtil.java
        M       parser/service/src/main/java/service/Log.java
        M       parser/service/src/main/java/service/ParseTableFilter.java
svn: In file 'subversion/libsvn_delta/text_delta.c' line 657: assertion failed (window->sview_len == 0 || (window->sview_offset >= ab->sbuf_offset && (window->sview_offset + window->sview_len >= ab->sbuf_offset + ab->sbuf_len)))
error: git-svn died of signal 6
```

How do I tackle this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: An assertion means there is a bug in git itself. I think your best option is to report a bug at http://git-scm.com/

Comment: Do you have local access to Subversion repository, i.e. via file:// protocol?

Comment: @radioversum, Yes I have access.

Comment: You should check the git svn reset answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156744/git-svn-rebase-checksum-mismatch

Answer (score 2):

You can try [SubGit](http://subgit.com) to import SVN repository into Git. Also, this tool allows using both Subversion and Git with the same repository.

Here are the basic instructions how to setup SubGit:

```
$ subgit configure SVN_REPOS
# Adjust SVN_REPOS/conf/subgit.conf to specify your branches and tags
# Adjust SVN_REPOS/conf/authors.txt to specify git & svn authors mapping
$ subgit install SVN_REPOS
...
# INSTALLATION SUCCESSFUL
```

After installation you can find imported Git repository at SVN_REPOS/.git; since this moment SubGit automatically synchronizes SVN and Git repositories on every `svn commit` and `git push`. In case you don't need this mirror functionality of SubGit, just run the command:

```
$ subgit uninstall --purge SVN_REPOS
```

This command deletes all the SubGit-related files, as result you have imported Git repository which is no more synchronized with SVN.

Find more details at [SubGit documentation](http://subgit.com/documentation/) and [git-svn](http://subgit.com/documentation/gitsvn.html) comparison pages.

SubGit is a commercial product, but it is free for one-time conversion. If you're interested in mirror mode of SubGit, it's free for open-source, academic and small projects (up to 10 committers).

Disclaimer: I'm one of SubGit developers.