# git svn fetch checksum mismatch error

Tags: git, svn

The `git svn fetch` throws the checksum mismatch error.

```
Checksum mismatch: pathto/web.xml bee95da33774b2dd11bf5430edfd7a315
expected: 018eb065a44eda65b848aksefhksdhf
     got: 2ae75279246a5602c058df8sdfsdkfs
```

I have referred the [git-svn-checksum-mismatch](http://www.victoriakirst.com/2010/12/git-svn-checksum-mismatch/) and the similar SO post [git-svn-rebase-checksum-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156744/git-svn-rebase-checksum-mismatch/8418829#8418829) and tried the provided solution. It doesn't resolve my problem.

When I execute the log and reset command, I am getting the below error.

```
git svn log pathto/web.xml
git svn reset -r5000 -p
```

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the
>   working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]' rev-list --first-parent
>   --pretty=medium HEAD: command returned error: 128

I am aware that this is very old version. We are using this old version for some other reason.

**git version 1.8.3.1**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover after a checksum mismatch with 'git svn clone'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402907/how-can-i-recover-after-a-checksum-mismatch-with-git-svn-clone)

Answer (score 1):

Got the same failure while synchronizing a repository with a recent new branch named '*cpa*', and was stuck on a certain revision of this branch whith errors such as '*checksum mismatch*' or '*index mismatch*', unsuccessfully trying `git svn reset` etc.

Finally I solved the problem by deleting all the refs of the failing branch, so that the next `git svn fetch` has refetched and rebuild the whole branch. It was a little bit brutal :

```
$ locate /cpa | grep /.git/
/pathrepo/.git/logs/refs/remotes/cpa@10343
/pathrepo/.git/refs/remotes/cpa@10343
/pathrepo/.git/svn/refs/remotes/cpa
/pathrepo/.git/svn/refs/remotes/cpa@10343
```

Verify that it is plausible and safe, then do :

```
$ locate /cpa | grep /.git/ | xargs rm -rf
$ git svn fetch
```

As I expected, `git svn fetch` has resync'd the exact tree, successfully this time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It indicates that your svn repository is corrupted and you need to dump and load your svn repository to continue. I have written [an extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42736821/506813) about this issue, hope it will be helpful.