# Git SVN Reset : Numeric SVN revision expected error

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

We're currently trying to convert a large SVN repository to Git. We ran into an issue where the HEAD revision in Git became corrupted somehow. We managed to fix that by running `git reset --hard /remotes/git-svn`.

When we try to do a `git fetch` now it comes up with a checksum mismatch. Tried following [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156744/git-svn-rebase-checksum-mismatch/8418829#8418829), but we're getting the following errors:

```
[xxxx@xxxx git-full]# git svn reset –r40117 –p
Numeric SVN revision expected

[xxxx@xxxx git-full]# git svn reset –r 40117 –p
Numeric SVN revision expected

[xxxx@xxxx git-full]# git svn reset -p –r 40117
Numeric SVN revision expected

[xxxx@xxxx git-full]# git svn reset -p –r40117
Numeric SVN revision expected

[xxxx@xxxx git-full]# git svn reset --parent –-revision=40117
Numeric SVN revision expected
```

We're trying in various different formats, but it's just not working. Currently using Git 1.7.12.4.

Comment: Did anybody find a workaround for this problem? I'm facing the exact same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced it and I was able to resolve it by changing 2 things.

```
- was using git on cygwin and now I tried with git for windows
- git for cygwin version was 2.16.1, git for windows version is 2.14.2.windows.1
```

One of those two things is causing the problem and I'm not going to run more experiments to see which is the culprit.